# Setting the Decimal to format ##.## in java

Tags: java, format, decimal

I am trying to build a map with time starting from 06.00 to 23:59 as keys and I will keep track of a number for each time as value.I need the time to stored HH.mm as format and I am planning to build the map using a loop by incrementing one minute and run the following code inside the loop.The problem here is since I have to set the format as HH.MM strictly I have to get the input as String and format it and then parse it back as double which affects the perfomance.Is there a global setting to change so that whatever double number I choose in this particular class should be of the format ##.##.Also point here to note is since it is time it ends at 60 minutes and hence I have to break the current iteration with the help of .6.

```
    Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
    //Edit:Moved DecimalFormat Outside the loop
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
    for (double time= 06.00; time<= 22.00; time= time+ 01.00)
    {

        String timeString = df.format(appointmentTime);
        time = Double.parseDouble(timeString);

        if (timeString.indexOf(".6") != -1)
        {
            time= time+ 00.40;

        }
        map.put(time,"<number>");
    }
```

Comment: I think your taking the wrong approach.What is it exactly you are trying to solve ?

Comment: I am trying to keep a common format ##.## for all the double values in a particular java class.Formatting individual elements affects performance.Hardcoding affects readablity and its a fluid Map and there may be step values from 1 minute to 30 so I can't hardcode it either.

Comment: If you are able to modify your sample program into one that compiles, runs, and prints out some meaningful values and messages, I think it will be easier for us to understand, and thus to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beliI believe you choose the most complicated approach. Instead of iterating the time variable you could iterate a simple number indicating the minutes since 0 o’clock and then generate your time double only for the map.

```
for(int totalMinutes = 6 * 60; totalMinutes <= 22 * 60; totalMinutes ++) {
    map.put(buildTimeDouble(totalMinutes),”<number>”);
}
```

But I believe (I do not understand your question in that point), it would be better not to use a double for the map key, instead you could use your own Time class, something like:

```
Time{
  private  int hour;
  private int minutes;

  public Time(int hour; int minutes) {
     this.hour = hour;
      this.minutes = minutes;
   }

   public toString(){
      return hour + “:” + minutes
   }

   public static Time fromTotalMinutes(int totalMinutesSinceZeroOclock){
      return new Time(totalMinutesSinceZeroOclock / 60; totalMinutesSinceZeroOclock / 60);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good approach to pre compute for all these values.Perhaps you can use a [LRU cache](http://java.dzone.com/news/inroducing-caching-java-applic).This can be easily implemented using a [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).I also think that you should not be using a double to represent time.Go through this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2001/jw-0330-time.html),it might give you some new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about performance, one modification you should make to your code is to construct the `DecimalFormat` just once, outside of the loop.  The same instance can be reused over and over again inside the loop.

Comment: actually this is a sample code and in my actual code its outside the loop , but my requirement is I should not do that at all.The input is an unformatted decimal and I convert it to a String and back to a parsed decimal

Answer (score 0):

You should not work with doubles as counters, as rounding errors will creep in giving off-by-one errors.

Instead have an integer counter from which you calculate the times you need.